# Complex numbers to represent a wall in heat conduction simulation

Tags: python, physics, complex-numbers

I am trying to represent a wall using the Thermal quadrupole method. I am more or less happy with the dampening factor, but the phase shift seems far too small. Why could this be?

Here is what I based my calculations on: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214157X22000120

```
import cmath
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Calculation
j = complex(0, 1)  # Imaginary unit

# Constants
w = (2 * np.pi) / (24 * 3600)
lamba = 1.10  # Thermal conductivity of the earth
rho = 1900  # Mass density of the earth
c = 1500  # Thermal capacity of the earth
D =lamba/rho*c  # Coefficient of diffusion
e = 0.04  # Thickness of earth
alpha=cmath.sqrt(j * w / D)
hcco=30
hcci=15


A=cmath.cosh(alpha*e)
B=(1/lamba*alpha)*(cmath.sinh(alpha*e))
C=lamba*alpha*cmath.sinh(alpha*e)
Dm=cmath.cosh(alpha*e)

Rcco=1/(hcco)
Rcci=1/(hcci)

H12=(A+Rcco*C)*Rcci+B+Rcco*Dm

H12_module, H12_argument = cmath.polar(H12)


# Phase shift
P = 24 * 3600
dephase = -(P / (2 * np.pi)) *H12_argument
dephase_h = dephase / 3600

# Damping factor

U = 1 /((1/hcci)+(1/hcco)+(e / lamba))  # Thermal transfer coefficient U = 1/Rtot
f = H12_module*U

# Time array
t = np.linspace(0, 48 * 3600, 288)

# Temperature equation

t0 = 30  # average temperature
tm = 10 #amplitude
tempe_ext= t0 + tm * np.sin(w * t + 105)
temp = (t0 + tm * np.sin(w * t + 105+dephase))*f

print(dephase_h)
print(f)
# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(t, temp, label='température intérieure')
plt.plot(t,tempe_ext,label='température extérieure')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.title('Temperature Variation')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the phase shift, and what did you expect it to be instead, and why?

Comment: @mkrieger1 with my code I have -0.00011688331119034377 hours and I would have like to have around -1 hour

Comment: What if -0.00011688331119034377 is correct and what you would like to have is incorrect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i am trying to match an experimental value where there is clearly a phase shift.

Comment: Are the values of `dephase`, `P`, and `H12_argument` what you expect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's the value of dephase that seems completly wrong to me . P is the period i chose 24hours

Comment: So `H12_argument` is correct?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i dont know what to expect for H12_argument